# Django - The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have run into a problem that I cannot figure out. First, my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import random

def pass_gen():
    password = ''
    def rand_uni():
        return random.randint(33, 126)
    def rand():
        return random.randint(8, 20)
    code = rand()
    for num in range(code):
        r_int = chr(rand_uni())
        password += r_int
    return password


# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Password(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    password = models.CharField(default=pass_gen(), max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['url', 'user'], name='unique_url_and_user_id')
        ]
```

Serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from vault.models import User, Password

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class PasswordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.CharField(max_length=800)

    class Meta:
        model = Password
        fields = ('url', 'password', "user")
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from vault.models import User, Password
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from vault.serializers import UserSerializer, PasswordSerializer

# Create your views here.

# GET list of all users
@csrf_exempt
def user_all(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

#GET and DELETE unique users  
@csrf_exempt
def user_detail(request, id):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    
    if request.method=='GET':
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
    
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        user.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
    
#get all passwords by unique user
@csrf_exempt
def passwords_one_user(request):
    user = request.GET.get('user')
    url = request.GET.get('url')
    password = Password.objects.filter(user=user).filter(url=url)
    try:
        passwords = Password.objects.filter(user=user)
    except Password.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    
    if request.method=="GET" and url==None:
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(passwords)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
    
    elif request.method=='POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
    
    elif request.method=="GET":
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(password)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
    
    elif request.method=='PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(password, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        password.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

Essentially, I can get the Users serializer to POST and GET data. I can POST a password to my db, but every time I attempt to GET a password, I get the error:

AttributeError at /password/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `url` on serializer `PasswordSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'url'.

(As a note, my url path to test the GET is http://localhost:8000/password?user_id=1).

Essentially I was just hoping to have this pull the passwords connected to the user that I specify in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You work with a `QuerySet` of `Password`s, so a collection (that can contain zero, one or more passwords). You thus need to work with:

```
if request.method == 'GET' and url == None:
    serializer = PasswordSerializer(passwords, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

beware that your `default=…` should *not* call the method, otherwise it will call it only once, when you start the server, and use that password for all… models it creates, which is likely a severe security problem, so:

```
import random

from django.db import models


def pass_gen():
    return ''.join(
        chr(random.randint(33, 126)) for _ in range(random.randint(8, 20))
    )


# …


class Password(models.Model):
    # …
    password = models.CharField(
        default=pass_gen, max_length=100  # 🖘 no parenthesis
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help! I am a student and this is my first real project in django. I will incorporate all of your suggestions here and report back. Thank you so much, again!

Comment: This completely fixed the problem and allowed me to troubleshoot the errors that came up as I worked through my other HTTP requests. I am so grateful for your help! Thank you!